# How get http params with in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

in this issue, if a user decides to reset the password a receive a param 
after clicking the HTTP redirects with a token like a screen below

[image: url]

so what's the approach to get this param?

because I've tried to fetch and set the params but fetch just set the after receive or post.
with axios the same, you need to already have anything stored to pass to the URL.

here is the exemple:

```
fetchParams() {

        return fetch('/password/reset/(:token_params -- how get and store this params?)' , {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",

            }
        }).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
    let token = res.token_params;

    console.log("token: ", token);

})
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }



fetchParams() {


axios.get('/password/reset/:params', {

  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);

  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });




}
```

so please someone can enlighten me how to get the params of a request in react before **.then?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the params form `props`.

get this params in this way, `token_param` is the param name it may change according to your path name.

```
componentDidMount() {
   console.log(this.props.match.params.token_param);
}
```

you can just call `this.props.match.params.token_param` where you want to access param.

Answer (score 0):

Would not work to get the params in react prior to the servers GET request (if this is a link from an email etc for password reset).
What you need to do is set up the page in React, and then it should have an ajax call to the server using this parameter.

I'm hoping I understood your question.

Comment: After trying to read your question again, I'm fairly certain I did not answer your question. Please rewrite the question so it's more coherent and succinct.

Comment: Emad thank you for answer, well. is not before the request but before .then